# How do I get view outside of an activity class

Tags: android, uiimageview, android-adapter

I am new to `Android`, I am working on a project about which I need to customize some views. I need to get some `imageview` from a layout that was inflated in some `BaseAdapter` like class. When I try :

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getView(R.layout.user_list_item).findViewById(R.id.iv_avatar);
```

I get error because in the `BaseAdapter` class there is

```
@Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
      final ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null)
      convertView = initialize(inflater.inflate(layout, null));
      try {
          update(position, convertView, getItem(position));
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return convertView;
  }
```

How do I get this `ImageView` ? I tried also `View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.user_list_item)`, but it didn't work

Here's how the views are initialized

```
public class UserListAdapter extends SingleTypeAdapter<User> {


    public UserListAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater, List<User> items) {
        super(inflater, R.layout.user_list_item);

        setItems(items);
    }
```

and this method

```
@Override
    protected int[] getChildViewIds() {
        return new int[] { R.id.iv_avatar, R.id.tv_name };
    }
```

as for `SingleTypeAdapter`, it comes like so

```
public abstract class SingleTypeAdapter<V> extends TypeAdapter {

  private static final Object[] EMPTY = new Object[0];

  private final LayoutInflater inflater;

  private final int layout;

  private final int[] children;

  private Object[] items;

  /**
   * Create adapter
   *
   * @param activity
   * @param layoutResourceId
   */
  public SingleTypeAdapter(final Activity activity, final int layoutResourceId) {
    this(activity.getLayoutInflater(), layoutResourceId);
  }

  /**
   * Create adapter
   *
   * @param context
   * @param layoutResourceId
   */
  public SingleTypeAdapter(final Context context, final int layoutResourceId) {
    this(LayoutInflater.from(context), layoutResourceId);
  }

  /**
   * Create adapter
   *
   * @param inflater
   * @param layoutResourceId
   */
  public SingleTypeAdapter(final LayoutInflater inflater,
      final int layoutResourceId) {
    this.inflater = inflater;
    this.layout = layoutResourceId;

    items = EMPTY;

    int[] childIds = getChildViewIds();
    if (childIds == null)
      childIds = new int[0];
    children = childIds;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_avatar);
```

Comment: `convertView` is not recognized

Answer (score 0):

I am not a pro of `Android` but you could try the following :

add in the `SingleAdpaterClass`

protected Activity activist = null;

and in `SingleTypeAdapter` adapter method, add this :

```
public SingleTypeAdapter(final Activity activity, final int layoutResourceId) {
    this(activity.getLayoutInflater(), layoutResourceId);
    activist = activity;
  }
```

this allows you to get an `Activity` instance in the `UserListAdapter` class, then you can get some view as so

```
View view = activist.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.user_list_item);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_list_item, null);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_avatar);
```